# Revolution slider black after transferring wordpress

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

Like usual I transferred a wordpress site from dev to public environment (both on the same online server).

Everything was fine except the revolution slider on the homepage. This one is turned black. Text although is correctly displayed.

Like usual I updated all the url's and scanned the database to be sure all was done.
However something strange happend to the slider. When I use the chrome dev tools is can see a link to the image: http://domain.com/uploads/.... that is correct. But when I open this link in a new tab i get: http://domain.com/**http:/**domain.com/uploads/....

I did a search on the database but no text whit http:/domain.com (notice the missing slash!).

However on the path displayed via dev tools the image is found.

Already tried to export the slider on dev version and import to live but nothing changed.

Also in the revolution slider table the path is set correct.

Any idea on how the path is created? Or how I Can solve this?
The one slider on this site isn't really an issue but I got one ready to launch tomorrow with 30+ sliders and I don't want to recreate them all.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather strang but here is the solution:

- change the permalink structure to something else
- turn back to what it must be

Never seen something like this before but it helped me to solve the issue.
Transfered 2 similar sites from the same dev server to the same live server with the same theme, wordpress version and slider and had no issues.